# How can I get Chrome to open, instead of save, torrent files

Tags: google-chrome, utorrent

If I click a link to a torrent file, Chrome always pops up the "Save As" box instead of asking if I want to save or open. How can I change this setting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

click the arrow next to the file button in the downloads bar and select `Always open files of this type`.

Comment: What if I want to ask me what to do?

Comment: "What if I want to ask me what to do?"...Chrome has never had that feature, its the only one I miss from IE